# Assign value of overlapping range with minimum duration to each day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

| start_day | end_day | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 3 |

I now want to generate a new DataFrame, where for each day (1-8) the value is determined by taking the value of the row where day is in [start_day, end_day] and the duration (end_day - start_day) is minimal. Eg:

| day | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |

Is there a way to do this without iterating through all the days and computing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new columns filled by `range`s, then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and last aggregate `min`:

```
df['day'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['start_day'], x['end_day']+1), axis=1)

df = df.explode('day').groupby('day', as_index=False)['value'].min()
print (df)
   day  value
0    1      1
1    2      1
2    3      1
3    4      1
4    5      2
5    6      2
6    7      3
7    8      3
```

EDIT:

```
df['duration'] = df.end_day - df.start_day
df['day'] = df.apply(lambda x: range(x['start_day'], x['end_day']+1), axis=1)

df1 = df.explode('day').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df1.loc[df1.groupby('day').duration.idxmin()]
print (df)
    start_day  end_day  value  duration day
0           1        4      1         3   1
1           1        4      1         3   2
2           1        4      1         3   3
3           1        4      1         3   4
8           1        6      2         5   5
9           1        6      2         5   6
16          1        8      3         7   7
17          1        8      3         7   8
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to slightly modify it with this: `df['duration'] = df.end_day - df.start_day`
`df.explode('day').groupby('day', as_index=False).apply(lambda df: df.loc[df.duration.idxmin()])['value']` to get it based on the min duration but this was a good start.

Comment: @ACB - thank you, I a bit change your solution.